# How to add a class to the body of the page, when the menu is open?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I created a "more" button at the bottom left of my site to display a menu.

When you click on the button, the + becomes x

https://www.s1biose.com/groupe/recettes-et-astuces

```
<div class="dropup">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown-menu-action" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="fa-4x">
      <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
        <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
        <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-plus" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-menu-action">
    <li><a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg"></i> Créer mon profil</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to add a class `.overlay-is-navbar-collapse` to the body of the page, when the menu is open and delete the class when the menu is closed ?

The following code does not work. If I click outside, the menu closes but the class remains on body.

```
  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('click', () => {
       $('body').toggleClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });
```

I have tried the following code, but it does not work :

```
  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your snippet should toggle the class on the body when you click the button

Comment: please provide a working example with all your code...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this,

```
 $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('click', () => {
   $('body').toggleClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
 });
$('.dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas').on('click', () => {
   $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
});
```

Comment: Instead of body you can remove class on `dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas` click, I've updated my answer pls check.

Comment: The code has no effect on my site. No class is added

Answer (score 0):

Use `.one` to attach a listener to the body *right when* the body's class gets added:

```
$('#dropdown-menu-action').on('click', () => {
  $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  $('body').one('click', () => {
    $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to elaborate more than "does not work", what's the error? Does the class not get removed, or what?

Comment: I added a link to my question. The class is not added.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
 $('dropdown-menu-action').click(function(){
        if($(body).hasClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse')){
            $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
        }
        else{
            $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
        }
});
```

Comment: I added a link to my question. The class is not added.